# Conversão de C para Java

Tags: java, c

Considerem um método que recebe 2 parâmetros e faz um cálculo para gerar um dígito verificador. Segue o trecho do código que estou com dificuldade:

```
char metodoDigito(char num, char qtos)
{

  short soma,
        peso,
        remainder;

  while( qtos ) 
  {
   soma += (*(num + --qtos) - '0') peso++;
  }

  remainder = soma % 11;
  return((char) ((remainder == 0 || remainder == 1) ? '0' : 59 - remainder));
                               /* = 11 - remainder + '0'*/
}
```

Alguns pontos:

- `while` em Java usamos `boolean` para dizer que a condição é verdadeira, nesse caso ele usa um `char`. Dicas de como transformar em Java?
- `soma += (*(num + qtos) - '0' ) peso++;` no final da soma ele multiplica pelo `peso++`?
- entendo que o `remainder` é o resto da divisão.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

> `while` em Java usamos `boolean` para dizer que a condição é verdadeira, nesse caso ele usa um char. Dicas de como transformar em Java?

Em C uma condição é falsa quando valer 0, qualquer outro valor é verdadeiro. Só isso. Em Java precisa ser explícito, então você verifica se a variável é diferente de zero explicitamente, usando o operador `!=` dá um resultado booleano que é o que o `while` espera.

> `soma += (*(num + qtos) - '0' ) peso++;` no final da soma ele multiplica pelo peso++?

Esse código não faz sentido e não compila.

Sugiro escrever um código do zero é melhor para aprender e para obter um resultado adequado.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, acho que você esqueceu um `*` antes do `peso++`, que aliás acho que deveria ser `++peso` no seu caso.

As variáveis `soma` e `peso` deveriam ser inicializadas. O valor inicial delas é zero.

Sugiro separar o uso dos operadores `++` e `--` em suas próprias instruções isoladas. Senão fica muito confuso. Como são incrementadas, decrementadas antes de serem usadas em `soma += ...`, então elas ficariam antes do `soma += ...`:

```
  while (qtos)
  {
      qtos--;
      peso++;
      soma += (*(num + qtos) - '0') * peso;
  }
```

No lugar do `while( qtos )` basta usar `while (qtos >= 0)`.

Acho que você queria que `num` fosse uma `String` e não um `char`. Se no seu código original, o `char num` fosse `char *num`, decerto seria isso. Se for esse o caso, o `*(num + qtos)` se tornaria em Java `num.charAt(qtos)`. Aliás, a variável `qtos` é o tamanho da `String`, e portanto não precisa ser passada como parâmetro, devendo ser definida com o valor inicial de `num.length()`.

Isso daqui pode ser simplificado:

```
remainder = soma % 11;
return ((char) ((remainder == 0 || remainder == 1) ? '0' : 59 - remainder));
```

O `(remainder == 0 || remainder == 1)` pode ser simplificado para `remainder <= 1`:

```
remainder = soma % 11;
return ((char) (remainder <= 1 ? '0' : 59 - remainder));
```

A ideia é retornar `11 - remainder`, exceto nos casos onde isso resultaria em 10 ou 11. Então, é possível fazer isso:

```
remainder = 11 - (soma % 11);
return (char) ('0' + (remainder >= 10 ? 0 : remainder));
```

Também é boa ideia declarar a variável apenas quando você for precisar dela.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
char metodoDigito(String num) {
    short soma = 0, peso = 0, qtos = num.length();

    while (qtos >= 0) {
        qtos--;
        peso++;
        soma += (num.charAt(qtos) - '0') * peso;
    }

    short remainder = 11 - (soma % 11);
    return (char) ('0' + (remainder >= 10 ? 0 : remainder));
}
```

Mais três observações:

- Tenho dúvidas se o melhor é retornar `char` ou retornar `int`, acho que `int` seria melhor.
- Também há pouca razão para se usar `short` em Java já que o tipo de inteiro padrão no Java é o `int`.
- O seu `while` também pode ser convertido em um laço `for`.
- Não faz muito sentido declarar o nome `metodo` em um método. É totalmente redundante e desnecessário. O nome `digitoVerificador` (ou mesmo apenas `dv`) seria melhor.
- Provavelmente esse método seria estático e público, pois não utiliza instâncias da classe onde está inserido e não aparenta ser uma funcionalidade interna de alguma classe.
- É possível ver que há uma relação entre o tamanho de `num`, `peso` e `qtos`. O valor de `qtos` começa em `num.length() - 1` e diminui até zero. O valor de `peso` vai de 1 até `num.length()`. De fato, no seu código, quando um aumenta o outro diminui. Com isso, podemos usar a relação `qtos == num.length() - peso` e então eliminar a variável `peso` e também podemos iterar os caracteres de `num` em qualquer ordem.
- Se iterarmos os caracteres de `num` na ordem que aparecem, podemos usar a sintaxe do *enhanced-for*.

Com isso, o código seria esse:

```
public static int digitoVerificador(String num) {
    int soma = 0, peso = 0;

    for (char c : num.toCharArray()) {
        peso++;
        soma += (c - '0') * peso;
    }

    int remainder = 11 - (soma % 11);
    return remainder >= 10 ? 0 : remainder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Respondendo seus pontos:

- A condição do `while` é equivalente à `qtos != 0`
- A linha `soma += (*(num + qtos) - '0' ) peso++;` dá erro de compilação. Precisa de uma operação (ou ponto e vírgula) ali entre os parênteses e o `peso++`
- Essa variável contém sim o resto da divisão por 11.

Comment: Digamos que possua um ponto e vírgula entre o parêntese e o peso++, qual o intuito de subtrair '0' da soma anterior? Esse código em C foi passado pra eu converter pra Java, não peguei da internet ou algo do tipo

Comment: Não sei o intuito, me parece estranho (para não dizer mal feito) o cálculo - não sei o objetivo dele. A subtração por `'0'` seria uma subtração [pelo código da letra, eu acredito](https://ascii.cl/). Acho que a idéia aqui é converter `num` para inteiro e fazer a subtração...